# Mock C# Constructor using NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, rhino-mocks

I have the following C# constructor which I want to mock (using NUnit+RhinoMocks):

```
public SMin(Dictionary<string, string> conf) : base(conf)
    {
        dat = Mgmt.Getbit<bool>(conf["D_BIT"]);
        avg = Mgmt.Getbit<bool>(conf["A_BIT"]);
    }
```

I tried the following:

I am creating mocks for Mgmt class, SMin and objects for variables(`dat & avg`) initialised in the constructor. Now, how do I mock the constructor, test it and assign the `dat and avg` initialised in the constructor to the mock objects I have created(`_dat & _avg`) for unit tests.

```
[TestFixture()]  
class SMinUTest
{

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
       var _mockMgmt = MockRepository.GenerateMock<Mgmt>();
       var _smin = MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<SMin>(null);
       var _dat = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IF_IO<bool>>();
       var _avg = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IF_IO<bool>>();
    }
...
...
}
```

Comment: is `Mgmt` a static class or instance used in class under test? if `SMin` is class under test then you don't mock it as you don't mock the class under test. you mock it's dependencies.

Comment: You are going to have to provide a [mcve] of the class under test and the expected behaviors.

Comment: @Nkosi Yes. SMin is the class under test. Mgmt is an instance used. SMin just has read and write functions which are used by dat & avg. How do I mock the constructor in this case ?

Comment: You dont mock the constructor you mock what is passed to the constructor.

Comment: Does `Mgmt` access any external resources that wont work during unit tests?

Comment: Yes, it accesses a config file(.txt) which is parsed into the Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an instance of Mgmt into SMin via your constructor. Ignoring the base class, SMin would look something like this:

```
class SMin
{
  // Just guessing at what type Mgmt is.. replace with your actual class name
  Management mgmt; // Instance passed in via constructor

  public SMin(Dictionary<string, string> conf, Management mgmt)
  {
    this.mgmt = mgmt;
    dat = mgmt.Getbit<bool>(conf["D_BIT"]);
    avg = mgmt.Getbit<bool>(conf["A_BIT"]);
  }
  // Other code
}
```

A test might then look something like this:

```
[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
  var conf = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  var _mockMgmt = MockRepository.GenerateMock<Management>();

  // TODO - Set expectations on _mockMgmt here, since the SMin constructor uses it

  // Create instance of SMin, passing in our mock
  var smin = new SMin(conf, _mockMgmt);

  // TODO - More test code, followed by assertions
}
```